# Javascript code for addEventListener not working!? (open enlarged img when clicked)

Tags: javascript, html

Whenever an image is clicked, the image should be displayed alone in a new window. It should be done completely in javascript (so no onclick functions in the HTML should be used) and with no jquery. I´ve done some research and have managed to get this far:

**Javascript**

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i=0; i < img.length; i++) {
   img[i].addEventListener("click", enlarge);
}

function enlarge() { 
   window.open(this.src); 
}
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens when any image is clicked and I can´t figure out why. Can anyone help me solve this problem of mine?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: isus, your code works fine check https://jsfiddle.net/3hgkaxgv/ You probably have something else attached to this event listener or its browser competibity

Comment: Seems to be working for me:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyBLBp

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/hu576dje/1/)

Comment: I use Chrome, so I don´t think the browser is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! 
The reason no clicks registrered (which turned out to be the issue as to why my code didn´t work for me) was because I put the `<script src="inlamning6.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>` *first*  in the HTML-document, namely right after the `<body>` tag. It should be *last* in the HTML-document, right before the `<body>`tag is closed. I moved it accordingly, and everything works fine now!

I thought that this could be valuable information if anyone else ever gets stuck on the same problem as I did here.

Answer (score 0):

your code should work fine check https://jsfiddle.net/3hgkaxgv/1/

The possible causes for your issue are:

Either browser compatibility or you already have something attached or catching click event.

**Edit:**

try the new changes if click registered was logged then you probably have popup disabled or something like that.

Try this instead of your code.

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i=0; i < img.length; i++) {
   img[i].onclick = enlarge;
}

function enlarge() { 
   console.log('click registered ');
   window.open(this.src); 
}
```

Comment: I know IE does not support addEventListener, but I´m using Chrome so there sould not be any problems there.

Comment: so first dont use addEventListener for now, see if it works for you, then if its not, you have something else in your code that bubble/catchs your click event. What you can try is adding a console.log to your enlarge function to see if the click registers. if so, then you have popups block of some sort

Comment: I really like your code above and it works in the jsfiddle you linked. But it does not work in my code when I insert it. I don´t have any popup blocks so it can´t be that either. My webpage has never blocked other popups such as `alert()` or `confirm()` functions. So as you say, there must be something that bubble/catchs my click event.

Comment: Did you check if the console.log appears ?

Comment: I´m coding in Atom (just a text editor) and I "see" the result in the browser. So I don´t use any generator that runs trough the code and shows the results like eclipse. This is part of an assignment in which no generators are allowed. But I guess I could try putting my code in jsfiddle and see if `console.log` appears there.

Comment: You "see" the result in browser - browser is all you need to see console.log - open your browser developer tool - you said your on chrome then that's f12, click f12 a window will open go the console tab and refresh the page.

Comment: Ah ok! I followed your instructions and console.log does not appear.

Comment: Then you have something else catching the click. cannot help you there.

Comment: Too bad... But I got a little bit wiser from your help so thank you! :)